# Homework: Why is catch being bypassed?

Tags: java, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
public static String userInput(Scanner input) {
    String date = "";
    int year = 0;
    try{
        System.out.print("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
        date = input.next();            
        boolean leapYear = getLeapYear(date);               
        boolean dateCheck = checkDate(date,leapYear);
        if(dateCheck == true) {
            return date;
        }           
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(year + " " + "is not a leap year");

    }
    return date;                
}
```

I have verified via debug that when I enter a non-leap year date such as 02/29/1601 that dateCheck is false. What I thought would happen is that when the if statement was false the program would proceed to the catch. Instead it is skipping completely over the catch and going to the return date. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose of a `catch` block?

Comment: Catch will execute only when exception occurs. It's not a replacement for control flow.

Comment: That's not what `catch` is for. [Here's a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) about what it is for.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - modify your comment by prepending 'Ask yourself, '

Comment: You're not getting `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: You should throw an Exception, not catch. Besides: where is IllegalArgumentException thrown?

Comment: @atmin Thank you for your comments. After thinking about it you are correct. The method asked for a Scanner object and it received one regardless of whether the user input was bad.  If I wanted to throw an exception that let the user know that their date was incorrect, what would be the best one to use?

Comment: "If I wanted to throw an exception that let the user know ..."--You're probably asking the wrong question.  First ask what you want the user to see.  If you want the user to see an error message saying the input was bad, then just make the program print one.  You don't **need** to throw an exception.  If you want the program to die and the user to see the whole exception backtrace thing, then `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` is OK, but that probably isn't necessary.

Comment: @ajb Thank you. Since I'm teaching myself and don't have a professor or classmates to help I really appreciate you and the other commenters as well as StackOverflow in general

Comment: @comfortablyNumb If you aren't taking a class for this, how is it homework?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch They are questions to problems that come at the end of the book I am using to teach myself.  Even if I'm not taking a class I still consider it homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is that your **checkDate** does not throw an **Exception**.

If you change:

```
   if(dateCheck == true) {
        return date;
   }
```

to

```
   if(dateCheck == false) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Check did not pass");
   }
```

you can throw one for him and it should work as you expect.

Comment: It would throw Exception if you enter "cxdcf234" as date or some other invalid value, that can not be parsed as date.

Answer (score 2):

Catch will only run when the body of the try throws an `Exception` (in your example only with an `IllegalArgumentException`). If you want the code to always run it should be in a [`finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) -

```
try{
    System.out.print("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ");
    date = input.next();            
    boolean leapYear = getLeapYear(date);               
    boolean dateCheck = checkDate(date,leapYear);
    if(dateCheck == true) {
        return date;
    } else {
        // what you seem to have expected.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a leap year");
    }        
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println(year + " " + "is not a leap year");
} finally {
    System.out.println("This will always print.").
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I see where I went wrong. Others have stated that an incorrect date is not an IllegalArgumentException.  OK. I can understand that. The method asked for a Scanner object and it received one. So what type of exception would a wrong date be? My goal is to stop the program and inform the user that they cannot enter February 29th in a non-leap year.

Comment: @comfortablyNumb Use a `Calendar`, and call [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)